# java servlet 404 not found

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

the servlet is

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ServletWriteHtml extends HttpServlet
{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException
{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    out.println("html" +
                "<body>" +
                "<h1 align = center>Write Html<h1>"
                + "<br>" + today + "<body>" + "</html>");                        
        }
}
```

the web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="file-upload" version="2.4" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>And</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ServletWriteHtml</servlet-class>
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletWriteHtml</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Alfa</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

the url is http://localhost:8080/JavaWeb/Alfa
compiled the servlet and class is in WEB-INF folder

HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
type Status report
messageNot Found
descriptionThe requested resource is not available.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1

Comment: You chose to name your servlet `And`. But then you map it using a different name: `ServletWriteHtml`. Also, unrelated, but your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You `servlet-name` should same in both servlet and servlet-mapping

And you need to give full path of class (including packages) in `servlet-class`

for example:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletWriteHtml</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.packages.ServletWriteHtml</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Comment: changed the web.xml , put ServletWriteHtml in java package still same error
404 page not found

        <servlet>
  <servlet-name>And</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>Javas.ServletWriteHtml</servlet-class>
 </servlet> 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>And</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Alfa</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: If `Javas` is your package and `JavaWeb` is your project now your Servlet should be called by  `http://localhost:8080/JavaWeb/And`

Comment: changed url to http://localhost:8080/JavaWeb/And still 404, also compiled ServletWriteHtml.java and the class file is in web-inf folder

Comment: I was confused by your solution, try http://localhost:8080/JavaWeb/Alfa

Comment: http://admin-pc:8080/JavaWeb/Alfa still 404